# Como saber se o Heroku está fora?

Tags: heroku

Estou enfrentando problemas de conexão, como saber se o servidor Heroku realmente está fora do ar ?

Comment: Consultou o [status](https://status.heroku.com)?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode conseguir essa informação acessando o seguinte link:

```
https://status.heroku.com/
```

Comment: Valeu !! realmente estava fora. você sabe algum outro servidor bom que seja realmente estável ?

Comment: @ironside como servidor gratuito acredito que o Heroku seja o melhor, mas se você estiver trabalhando numa aplicação que realmente precise estar online sempre recomendo uma solucão paga, como a [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/).

Comment: valeu ... notei que o heroku parece não ser um bom servidor. preciso de um que seja dedicado. vou ver esse AWS